# UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier unique or not?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

This may sound a newbie question, however I'm new to iOS dev,

I want to understand when I should use UNIQUE identifier for the cells and when not for

```
- (id)dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier
```

Actually in lots of places I've met code snippets where identifier was not unique.

But in my practice I've used unique identifier in order to keep the order of the UITableViewCells, otherwise the order was mixed when I've scrolled UITableView up and down.

So please help me to understand the concept of reusable cells, shan't each cell have unique identifier?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I've got the answer to my question. Thanks to Aaron's question.
I always try to initialize each cell only once in the same view (of course if it's not being edited in that view). I do this to enhance the performance and smooth the scrolling of the table view.
The difference is - now I know how it works. If I get it right, cell identifier makes the cells to stay unique and this way table does something like caching that information and then putting it to the right place (because of unique identifiers).

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 2):

You should use different identifiers only for different types of cell.  If your table view had different classes of cell this may be your problem, or you have added subviews to a cell that vary in their presence from cell to cell.

When using an identifier, think about it in terms of your cell could contain the data of any previously rendered cell data, so you need to ensure your code overwrites that data, in the most simple case cell.textLabel.text.

Comment: I do use the same type for all cells, and subviews of cells have the same types. I.e. all the cells have one image and three text labels. All these parts are NOT empty. But I still have mixed cells after scrolling.

Comment: @jackal: In `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, do you assign the correct values to all the labels and images every time? Even when you dequeue, you need to set those.

Comment: @jackal: Check what Aaron is saying. Also, it could be a function of your model. How is you data stored? Are you sure you its sort order is consistent?

Comment: @sosborn: Thank you. I get it. Aaron's question helped me to understand it (check my answer)

Answer (score 0):

Always try to initialize each cell only once in the same view . I do this to enhance the performance and smooth the scrolling of the table view. The difference is - now I know how it works. If I get it right, cell identifier makes the cells to stay unique and this way table does something like caching that information and then putting it to the right place.